# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Erro inflating class fragment Caused by:

Tags: android-studio

Al iniciar el fragmento en mi aplicación aparece esto:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error
>   inflating class fragment Caused by:
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to
>   instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment:
>   calling Fragment constructor caused an exception at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:386) at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:33)
>   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment$2.instantiate(Fragment.java:2320)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3706)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430) at
>   com.example.ernes.programa.Maps.onCreateView(Maps.java:35) at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6365) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773) Caused
>   by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:364) ... 28
>   more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment$zzb; at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.(Unknown Source)
>   ... 31 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb at
>   java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:362) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) ... 32 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class
>   com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza extended by class
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb is inaccessible
>   (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb'
>   appears in /data/app/com.example.ernes.programa-1/base.apk) ... 32
>   more

Mi Xml es este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Maps">


<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map1"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
```

he investigado hasta en ingles y no puedo encontrar la solución,  ya he intentado las otras preguntas similares a esta pero no me funciona, se supone que al abrir el fragmento debe aparecer el google maps pero no, mi activity Maps esta correcto eso ya lo verifique miles de veces, espero y me puedan ayudar, Gracias por su atención.

build.glradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ernes.yovigilo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
```

buildscript {

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files

}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment` no estás implementando la clase `com.google.android.gms.maps` en tu app. Dice que no encuentra la clase. ¿Podrías mostrar el `gradle` de la carpeta `app`? Una clave para entender los largos mensajes de error de Java es ir a la parte que dice `Caused by...`

Comment: Claro! gracias por contestar y por ayudarme!

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor mira los enlaces para saber como funcionamos!

Comment: Parece correcto. Puede que te falte algún otro paso en la configuración de la API, a nivel de permisos en el manifest, la clave de API, la instalación del SDK de Maps u otra cosa. Por favor [revisa aquí los diferentes pasos de la documentación](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start) y compara con lo que tienes en tu proyecto.

Comment: Gracias por el link, tengo todo igual con la diferencia de que uso fragment no fragmentActivity, tengo ya validada la api key de google, el manifest esta correcto ya e investigado y tengo todo lo que me faltaba solo que me bota este mensaje de error al querer abrir este fragment

Comment: La API de `maps` va por su versión 15, no sé por qué tienes la versión 8. Esta es la versión más reciente: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1`

Comment: Gracias en verdad por tu ayuda esto resolvió mi gran problema! GRACIAS!

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a al comentario de

> La API de maps va por su versión 15, no sé por qué tienes la versión 8. Esta es la versión más reciente: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1 – A. Cedano

Se resolvió mi problema, fue algo tan sencillo que me dio coraje y felicidad, en verdad gracias por su tiempo y comentarios de gran ayuda.